# Search with like and Left Join

Tags: php, mysql, join

I am working on a search query where it gets a terms and shows results for it. I have figured out most of it. However my problem is in the query, Its suppose to search for categories and it brings them up but its also suppose to bring up the products in the categories.

**Query**

```
$query = "SELECT brands.braname, brands.braimg, brands.braid, Products.proid, Products.name FROM brands
LEFT JOIN Products ON brands.braid = Products.proid
WHERE braname LIKE $search ORDER BY braid ASC LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to add my problem is that its not bringing up the products for each category in the search.

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. Can you please add an example of the output you currently get, and the output you really want?

Answer (score 0):

LEFT JOIN Products ON brands.braid = Products.proid 
Do the "Products" has braid? 
Maybe it would be ON LEFT JOIN Products ON Products.braid = brands.braid

Comment: Yes products, has brand id

Answer (score 0):

Try adding some wildcards on your search item, like:

```
........ LIKE %".$search."% ORDER BY braid ASC LIMIT 1";
```

Answer (score 0):

LIKE requires a string as its input so you need single quotes. Like this:

```
$query = "SELECT brands.braname, brands.braimg, brands.braid, Products.proid, Products.name 
FROM brands LEFT JOIN Products 
ON brands.braid = Products.proid 
WHERE braname LIKE '".$search."' ORDER BY braid ASC LIMIT 1";
```

Also if you aren't using any wildcards, you might as well stop confusing yourself and use '=' instead of 'LIKE':

```
$query = "SELECT brands.braname, brands.braimg, brands.braid, Products.proid, Products.name 
FROM brands LEFT JOIN Products 
ON brands.braid = Products.proid 
WHERE braname = '".$search."' ORDER BY braid ASC LIMIT 1";
```

If you need to check whether the column braname **includes $search**, then you need to use the **'%'** wildcard which stands for any number of any symbols:

```
$query = "SELECT brands.braname, brands.braimg, brands.braid, Products.proid, Products.name 
FROM brands LEFT JOIN Products 
ON brands.braid = Products.proid 
WHERE braname LIKE '%".$search."%' ORDER BY braid ASC LIMIT 1";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$query = "SELECT brands.braname, brands.braimg, brands.braid, Products.proid, Products.name
          FROM brands
          LEFT JOIN Products ON brands.braid = Products.proid 
          WHERE braname LIKE %$search% 
          ORDER BY braid ASC 
          LIMIT 1";
```

You need add percentage simbols rounding the search terms.